# Javascript: запись fn(arg1)(arg2)...(argN)

Tags: javascript, функции

Прошу прощения, если вопрос идиотский. Изучаю JS и функциональное программирование, и не совсем понимаю что означает данная запись. Хотелось бы понять, что в общих чертах происходит тут?

Comment: Не JS-программист, но похоже, что fn(arg1) возвращает функцию, которая вызывается с аргументом arg2 и возвращает функцию, которая вызывается с аргументом arg3 ... и возвращает функцию, которая вызывается с аргументом argN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё очень просто.
Представьте, что есть функция:

```
function test1(x) {
  return { foo: x + 10 };
```

На вызов `test1(5)` функция вернёт объект `{ foo: 15 }`:

```
const result = test1(5);
console.log(result.foo); // 15
```

У нас нет необходимости записывать результат в отдельную переменную и мы спокойно можем вывести число 15 следующим синтаксисом:

`console.log(test1(5).foo) // 15`

то есть после закрытия скобки в данном месте нужно считать, что у нас есть результат вызова функции.

А теперь посмотрим на функцию `test2`:

```
function test2(x) {
  return function(y) {
     return { foo: x, bar: y }
  }
}
```

Наша `test2` возвращает функцию, которая принимает аргумент и возвращает объект `{ 
foo: x, bar: y }`. Пример вызова:

```
const newFunction = test2(5);
console.log(newFunction(10)); // { foo: 5, bar: 10 }
```

Однако нам так же нет необходимости заводить отдельную переменную и мы можем воспользоваться уже известным синтаксисом:

```
console.log(test2(5)(10));
```

На всё это дело нужно смотреть как на вызов функции, полученной после вызова функции test2.

Для вашего примера:
`fn(arg1)(arg2)...(argn)`
нужно читать:
вызов функции, полученной после предыдущего вызова функции, полученной после предыдущего вызова функции,... полученной после вызова функции `fn`.

Прочитайте про каррирование и будет ещё понятнее.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, Михаил!